# What happens to my rep if an answer is migrated to a stack where I'm not a member?

Tags: discussion, reputation, migration

I answer [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504847/tongue-in-cheek-word-for-a-mysteriously-attractive-man) -- which, I'll admit, already has a couple close votes, but which seems to be to be a pretty simple and on-topic ask.  An hour or so later, I get a notification that my answer has been migrated.

Presuming I get upvotes on the answer, what happens to the rep?  I'm not a member there, so I presumably have (and will continue to have) zero reputation -- but the (presumed) upvotes will generate rep.  Does it just go into limbo?  If I were to later join that stack (unlikely, but not impossible, at least in this case) would I get that rep?  Or would I need to join there before the votes to collect?